# Having an issue getting a player to change positions relative to a boat's rotation

Tags: trigonometry

What I'm trying to do is make it look like the boat is moving the player with it as the boat turns. As of now, when the boat turns, the player just stays in the same x, y position and looks like he is sliding in a circle.

I have been stuck on this for a few days now and I can't figure out how to solve this. I know that I need the angle the boat is facing, the player's distance from the center of the boat, and a way to make the player's position dependent on the boat's rotation, but I don't know the mathematical equation I need.

Here's a visual reference I've created:

[image: position of player inside boat]

Comment: How are you rotating the boat itself in the first place?

Comment: I'm rotating the boat by using the direction the player is facing. If the ((boat's directional angle - player's directional angle) < -7.5) then the boat will rotate to the right. So it rotates by using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Try using polar coordinates, it would show the player's coordinates with respect to the radius(distance from boat) and angle of rotation.

Comment: I'll look into these polar opposites. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: So I've been reading about these polar coordinates and I can't seem to understand how they would work with the boat's rotation. From what I understandof this equation: tan^(-1)(y/x) I'm just plugging in the player's x, y coordinates and then solving for the angle above the x-axis. I don't really understand how this would take into account the boat's rotation. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: May you please post a visual so that I can understand the question better, not to fall in any miss-understanding

Comment: Here you go: https://i.imgur.com/3GekCvu.png thank you for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, still, the problem is not so clear for me,
what's the player doing exactly again?

Comment: So if you put the player at position (3, 0) and you rotate the boat 90°, then you would expect the player to be at position (0, 3). Problem is, no matter what direction or how much you rotate the  boat, the player will always be at position (3, 0). This makes it look as though the player is sliding across the boat in a circle around the boat's center. Hope this clears it up. I'll try to clarify more if needed.

Comment: Should I provide more clarification?